# C# static member not adding in array

Tags: c#

I'm learning C#, and as a part of this going through some online tutorials. I like to deviate slightly from the tutorial sometimes, to see if I can really grasp the ideas being presented.

I've created a test program that creates an array of a class I've defined, called "Machine." One class member is a **static int**, used to keep track of how many times the class is initialized.

The method tied to the **static int** is in the class constructor, which adds one to the **static int** each time the constructor is called. I would expect, then, that each time the class is initialized in my array, that the **static int** increases by one. However the actual result shows that it does not increase at all.

Code and results are at the bottom.

When learning about static members, I thought static members "are initialized before the static member is accessed for the first time and before the static constructor, if there is one, is called" (from MSDN's [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79b3xss3.aspx)). If this is so, shouldn't this layout work? Thank you for any comments or suggestions.

Code:

```
using System;

public class Machine
{
  public string model {get; set;}
  public int hours {get; set;}
  public static int num = 0;

  public Machine() // constructor
  {
    model = "Cat";
    hours = 0;
    num = num ++; // count how many times class initialized
  }

  public void display() // display method
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Machine #{0} Info: Model: {1}, Hours: {2}",
    num, model, hours.ToString());
  }
}

public class PMScheduler
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    int fleetnum = 5, i;
    Machine[] mymach = new Machine[fleetnum]; // declare

    // initialize the array
    for (i=0; i < fleetnum; i++)
    {
      mymach[i] = new Machine();
    }

    // set the values on the first two
    mymach[0].model = "RJS";
    mymach[0].hours = 1000;
    mymach[1].model = "REX";
    mymach[1].hours = 2000;

    // display all
    foreach (Machine mymach_i in mymach)
    {
      mymach_i.display();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Machine #0 Info: Model: RJS, Hours: 1000
Machine #0 Info: Model: REX, Hours: 2000
Machine #0 Info: Model: Cat, Hours: 0
Machine #0 Info: Model: Cat, Hours: 0
Machine #0 Info: Model: Cat, Hours: 0
```

Comment: Your `num = num ++;` should be `num++;`. The reason being that `num++` as a method doesn't return anything, so `num` becomes `0` again.

Comment: @siva `num++` returns `num`.

Comment: @siva.k, `num++` does return a value, the value is whatevers is in `num` before it is incremented.

Comment: @BlueM oh, interesting, thanks. Of course now I can't edit my comment so my idiocy will always be known, NOOO!!!!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - please see my answer below for some things that pertain to the num++ issue.

Comment: Its interesting how num=num++ will increment after returning, but the return trump the increment. num doesn't change. But if you did x = num++, it is the equivalent of x = num; num++.

Comment: @KarlKieninger Its not incremented after return, it just returns the old value after the increment.

Comment: @BlueM: Yeah, I wasn't 100% clear. num++ *wants* to increment after "returning" num, but in this case it effectively could not because it the incremented values is being over written by the return. Basically the sequence is this: retunVal = num; num = num + 1; num = returnVal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace This:

```
num = num ++;
```

With This:

```
num = num + 1;
```

Comment: Or just replace it with `num++` :)

Comment: No! Use `num += 1;` or `num = ++num;` :P

Comment: @BlueM, or `++num` or `num = 2 + num - 1`. They all do the same thing.

Comment: @BlueM, `++num` would better than `num++`.

Comment: @Ash No difference. This is a story from C++ in my opinion.

Comment: @Ash if you are not using the result of the operation, then there is no difference between `++num` and `num++` - they both do exactly the same thing to `num`, except return different results. Since OP isn't using the result, there is no difference.

Comment: @theyetiman Thanks for clearing that up. I quickly tested it and the compiler optimizes it if the value is not used.

Comment: @theyetiman, no they do differ, `num++` has to create a copy where as `++num` does not. After a quick test, `++num` is definatly faster than `num++` although very minimal. 1000000000 iterations using `++num` saved on average 500000 ticks.

Comment: That's interesting if correct. I coded an example with `++num` and an example with `num++` and compared the IL - they are identical.

Comment: @Ash 

.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 i)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloc.0
  IL_0004:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0005:  add
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I tested the same as you and it was the same time IF its not assigned to another variable.

Comment: @theyetiman, it's appears to be the same IL when compiled to Release. This is the same IL as `++num` built to Debug.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko yup - my comment above is for debug, but the IL is the same for `++num` and `num++` if you compile to release as well. The debug IL just has an extra `nop` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found two things. The first is that I should've used "num++." Stupid on my part. The second is that, since I display after all instances of the class are initialized, my **static int** will only display the total number of times the class has been initialized, not a running count.

So, if I replace the class definition with this, the result is as expected:

```
public class Machine
{
  public string model {get; set;}
  public int hours {get; set;}
  public static int totalnum = 0;
  public int num;

  public Machine() // constructor
  {
    model = "Cat";
    hours = 0;
    num = totalnum;
    totalnum ++; // count how many times class initialized
  }

  public void display() // display method
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Machine #{0} Info: Model: {1}, Hours: {2}",
    num, model, hours.ToString());
  }
}
```

Sorry for the stupid mistake. And, I'd welcome any other comments on if this is a "bad" way of counting the number of times a class has been initialized in an array.

Comment: You don't post an answer to your own question when others have provided you the answer.

Comment: You said you found 2 things but only explained 1.

Comment: Traditionally there is no space put between before the ++. Using i++ look standard and i ++ give the eye a pause. Syntactically okay in C#, but probably best to avoid the space.

Answer (score 0):

In `num = num++` the value before incrementation is being assigned to `num`;

This is basically what happens behind the scenes:

First `num++` is evaluated to posses the value before incrementation. This value is 0 right now.

then `num++` is evaluated so `num++ = num + 1` which gives it the value of 1;

lastly assignment takes place, but instead of assigning 1 to `num`, the old value before the incrementation is assigned to num;

This is a little counter-intuitive. But as mentioned replacing `num = num++;` with just `num++;` or `num = ++num;` will fix your problem.